# Autofolding a code block in vim

Tags: vim

I have a lot of unittests in my code base, it would be nice if I could auto fold them.

The structure of unittests are

```
unittest{
    //...
}
```

I have never written in vimscript before but I managed to get something that roughly works

```
function! UnittestFold()
  let thisline = getline(v:lnum)
  if match(thisline, '^unittest') >= 0
    return ">1"
  endif
  if match(thisline, '^}') >= 0
    return "0"
  endif
  return "="
endfunction
setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=UnittestFold()
```

There are a few issues with this code, the closing bracket `}` of the unittest block is not inside the fold.

I also can not use `zA` to open all folds and I have no idea why. `No folds found`

I think the problem is that I set the foldlevel to 0 for every closing bracket. Also I probably can not use `{` or `}` inside the unittest block.

How would I indicate that the fold should end after the last `}` of unittest block?

Comment: Why don't you use `set foldmethod=indent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are a few issues with this code, the closing bracket } of the unittest block is not inside the fold.

I can not test it right now, but changing the `return "0"` statement to `return "s1"` could help.

> I also can not use zA to open all folds and I have no idea why.

When you enter `:h zA` in Vim you see that `zA` does not open all folds. To open all folds, press `zR` (to close all `zM`).

> Also I probably can not use { or } inside the unittest block.

You should be able to use those brackets inside the unittest block. `match(thisline, '^}') >= 0` is only true when a closing bracket appears at the very first column of a line - which is not the case if you use spaces. The hat (`^`) in this statement is a regular expression meaning the beginning of a line of code.

The only thing that will not work with this code is if you have something other than `unittest { ...}` at the same level. If you only use unittest for your file, you should be fine.